# not able to ping mongoDB instance in same VPC

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, networking, amazon-vpc

i have two EC2 instances

1- running springboot application

2- mongoDB instance

both EC2 instances are in same VPC and i am able to ping mongoDB instance from spring boot application using privateIP
but when my springboot application is trying make DB connection to mongoDB instance it is getting timed out

in my inbound rule for DB instance i have allowed all ICMP-IPv4 on all ports and TCP connection on 27017 port with springboot application security group as the source.

Comment: Is your Spring Boot application connecting to the private IP of the MongoDB instance? Or a DNS-resolved hostname? If the latter, are you using the regular AWS-supplied VPC DNS server?

Comment: it is using private IP to connect mongoDB

Comment: can you share inbound and outbound of both security groups (DB and instance)?